# C# Winfroms GUI Documentation

Tags: c#, documentation-generator

For a library project without a GUI I'm using XML documentation tags in my C# code and Sandcastle to create a help / documentation file for the API. I really like this, because every time I add something to the code I'm adding as well the XML documentation tags (otherwise I see a compiler warning) and the documentation stays always up to date.

On the other hand if I've a Winforms application and I want to describe the GUI I'm doing it by hand at the moment using Word or LaTeX:

1. Take screen shots of every form (and every tab page on the form)
2. Describe all controls on that form (or tab page)

Is there a way to automate that? Similar to the XML documentation tags and the Sandcastle approach.
For example I could describe each control in the `ToolTipText` property of the control. But how could I generate a help / documentation file from that which includes as well screen shots?

Comment: I've moved this question from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922473/c-sharp-winfroms-gui-documentation